# How to add power governors?

Tags: kernel, power-management, cpufreq, governor

my cpu is Intel n3710 , on Ubuntu 20.04 , I installed cpu freq utils , but it shows available cpufreq governors as only powersave and performance. Can we add other governors like ondemand , conservative and userspace? If yes how?
Thanks.

Comment: Intel `pstate` has only these governors, You can remove pstate, but that is a very poor decision.

Answer (score 1):

The Intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver has included a passive mode for some time now. In that mode the scaling driver is called intel_cpufreq, and it has all of the same governors as acpi-cpufreq.

To look at what you have now do:

```
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
```

Opps bad example (on purpose, to show acpi-cpufreq).
Try again:

```
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
```

And indeed only performance and powersave governors are available:

```
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
```

Now, let's look at the intel_pstate driver settings:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status
active
```

And change it to passive mode:

```
$ echo passive | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status
passive
doug@s15:~/temp$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status
passive
```

Now check the cpufreq same stuff as before:

```
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
```

NOTE: For users with HWP (HardWare Pstate control) capable processors: Currently, passive mode is only possible if the system is booted with HWP disabled and/or passive mode forced at boot. Passive with HWP enabled might be in the future.
Here are a few example grub command lines for various methods of intel_pstate boot:

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=450 cpuidle_sysfs_switch cpuidle.governor=teo"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=450 intel_pstate=no_hwp cpuidle_sysfs_switch cpuidle.governor=teo"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=300 intel_pstate=disable cpuidle_sysfs_switch cpuidle.governor=teo"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=450 intel_pstate=passive cpuidle_sysfs_switch cpuidle.governor=teo"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=450 intel_pstate=passive intel_pstate=no_hwp cpuidle_sysfs_switch cpuidle.governor=teo"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=450 intel_pstate=passive intel_pstate=no_hwp cpuidle_sysfs_switch cpuidle.governor=teo intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=450 intel_pstate=passive cpuidle_sysfs_switch cpuidle.governor=teo cgroup_no_v1=all"
```